# Is "Popping Popcorn" a Stochastic Process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

While placing a bag of popcorn in the microwave today, I noticed the following thing:

- In the 30 seconds, the time difference between (e.g. treat "time" as a random variable) which any two kernel of popcorn can pop has some probability distribution function (e.g. the n-th kernel pops at time T1 and the n_1-th kernel pops at time T2 : T2 - T1 has some probability distribution
- In the next 30 seconds, the time difference between which any two kernels of popcorn can pop has some other probability distribution - naturally, the time difference between successive kernel pops is obviously shorter
- In the last 30 seconds, the time difference between which any two kernels of popcorn can pop has another probability distribution - naturally, the time difference between successive kernel pops is longer than this same time difference in the previous 30 seconds.

This brings me to my question - **could "popping popcorn" be modelled as some Stochastic Process** (such as a Inhomogeneous Poisson Arrival Process, Markov Switching Process or a Brownian Motion ) ?

For instance, suppose we knew that 43 kernels of popcorn have already popped - we also know that time at which each kernel popped (e.g. kernel_1 = 12 seconds, kernel_2 = 19 seconds, kernel_3 = 21 seconds .... kernel_42 = 81 seconds, kernel_43 = 85 seconds). This means we also know the time differences between each successive pair of popcorn kernels (e.g. Kernel_2_1 = 19 - 12 = 7 seconds, Kernel_3_2 = 21 - 19 seconds = 2 seconds, etc.). With this information (and historical data we collected about popcorn kernels popping) , **could we make some inference as to when the 44th kernel of popcorn is expected to pop?**

Thanks!

**Note 1:** I feel a very naive way to approach this problem would be to just fit some regression model through historical data - here I have shown this using the R programming language.

```
library(dplyr)
    #first 30 seconds
    popping_times = abs(rnorm(40,10,3))
    index = 1:40
    data_1 = data.frame(index, popping_times)

#next 30 seconds
popping_times = abs(rnorm(80,5, 2))
index = 1:80
data_2 = data.frame(index, popping_times)

#next 30 seconds
popping_times = abs(rnorm(30,7,3))
index = 1:30
data_3 = data.frame(index, popping_times)

total_data = rbind(data_1, data_2, data_3)
total_data$index = 1:nrow(total_data)

total_data = data.frame(total_data %>%  mutate(popping_times_diff = abs(popping_times - lag(popping_times))))

total_data[is.na(total_data)] <- 0
```

The data looks something like this:

```
 index popping_times popping_times_diff
1     1     10.380158         0.00000000
2     2      8.874496         1.50566244
3     3      8.966483         0.09198782
4     4      9.312913         0.34642958
5     5     11.094466         1.78155287
6     6      9.707844         1.38662218
```

And the plots look something like this:

```
plot(total_data$index, total_data$popping_times, main="Popping Times of Popcorn Kernels", xlab="Kernel Index", ylab="Popping Time (Seconds)", type = "b")

plot(total_data$index, total_data$popping_times_diff, main="Popping Time Difference of Popcorn Kernels", xlab="Kernel Index", ylab="Popping Time Difference (Seconds)", type = "b")
```

[image]

**Note 2:** If we aggregated the data into "number of kernels that popped within each 10 second interval" - we might be able to make a time series model (e.g. ARIMA) that predicts how many kernels will pop in the next 10 seconds ... but this is a slightly different problem from the one I am interested in

Comment: All I have in mind is a renewal process, because at every single time $t_0$ a popcorn pops, you have a new waiting time that starts from $t_0$.

Comment: @ Hamdiken: Thank you! This is a very clever observation!

Comment: You can make a model like this, sure -- this falls into the "all models are wrong, but some are useful" category. I don't think I know a theoretical reason that a stochastic process based on the *times between pops* would be a useful direction to go, though; I bet (just as a completely off-the-cuff opening bid) that simply simulating $n$ kernel pops, each of which are normally distributed with $\mu = 90$ seconds and $\sigma = 10$ seconds (e.g.; replace w/ something estimated from data, or a different distribution entirely) might more closely adhere to reality.

Comment: And while you can certainly explore the interarrival times of such a process, the mathematics involved are often intractably difficult to do much with in a closed form. I don't think a renewal process would do a good job modeling this, though, because the interarrival times are certainly *not* i.i.d. -- they should be sparse at the beginning and end, and dense in the middle.